# Displaying a large image as a series of tiles

Tags: html, css

I need to display a network diagram on a web page. The diagram will be too large to display as a single image, so I would like to display it in a similar fashion to google maps, i.e break it into tiles and allow the user to scroll around the image.

I also need to be able to overlay status information on to this diagram.

How would I go about breaking up an image into tiles, then displaying them on a website, while also overlaying data using some form of co-ordination system?

I have found a few tutorials and libraries online, however these all seem to relate to geospacial data from google/openstreetmap etc. As this is not geographical based, these resources do not seem to do what I need.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of the correct terms for what I need, to create appropriate tags. If anyone can suggest more appropriate tags, please re-tag this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many scripts out there just like Google-Maps, and some of it is better, one of them called **[Custom Interactive Map](http://codecanyon.net/item/custom-interactive-map-jquery-plugin/6275001)** from CodeCanyon, using the Json + SVG,
that's [alive preview](http://beta.newnozha.com) i made months ago, Some sites released it for free, you search for it.
And you can find alot of free scripts doing the same here:

- [20+ Useful jQuery Google Maps Tutorials and Plugins](http://designmodo.com/jquery-google-maps-tutorials-plugins/)
- [50+ Best jQuery Map plugin with Demo examples](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-map/)
- [16 Best Free jQuery Map Plugins](http://codegeekz.com/best-jquery-map-plugins/)

Also you can find other scripts by searching with this keywords:

> jquery map viewer like google maps

Comment: Does Custom Interactive Map support tiles? From what I can see of the demos, it only loads a single background image, which is probably not going to work in my case. The links seem to be mainly plugins for working with google maps, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Custom Indetactive Map custom images, you can use SVG or JPG